# Surface area of a regular, orientable, compact surface with positive Gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

**Problem: Let $S$ be a regular, orientable, compact surface with positive Gaussian curvature: $K ≥ M >
0$. Prove that the surface area of $S$ is less than $\dfrac{4\pi}{M}$**

*Ideas: From the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem, we have that
$$\int_S K=2\pi\chi(S)$$
As a corollary, we have that if $K>0$, then $S$ is homeomorphic to a sphere, which has $$\int_SK=2\pi\chi(S)=4\pi$$
However, I am not quite sure how to sure that the surface area would be less than $\dfrac{4\pi}{M}$. What other ideas do I need?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surface area of $S$ is given by $\int_S 1$, and

$$4\pi = 2\pi\chi(S) = \int_S K \geq \int_S M = M\int_S 1.$$